# Send redirect url instead of redirect in Laravel for ajax calls

Tags: ajax, laravel, authentication, redirect

I try to update laravel auth with ajax login and signup. I have the login form that sends ajax POST request to /login path. Everything works except the case when the user successfully signing in - in this case laravel returns redirect to /home page.

Is it possible to prevent this behavior? I would like to get something like `{message:"User signed in",redirect_to:"/home"}` instead of the actual redirect.

For now I just copied sendLoginResponse method from `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers` to the `Auth/LoginController` and rewrote it like this:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    //return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
    //        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: ["message"=>"User successfully logged in"];
}
```

I don't like it. Is there more natural way? Is it possible to force laravel to return redirect_to url instead of making the actual redirect for every ajax request?

Comment: so you want to show the message then redirect to your custom route,is that your question ?

Comment: [The docs include a guide on customising the built in authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users) - is that not suitable for you?